# Create Different List Values into HashMap From One Main List

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a object list like;

```
List <Object> mainList = new ArrayList <Object>();
List <Object> tempList = new ArrayList <Object>();
```

I want to divide mainList into hashMap. My hashMap would be like;

```
Map<String, List<Object>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
```

Key and list value will be obtained from mainList. Each key has more than one value, so i create `hashmap (key, <list> value)`.

I parse mainList to tempList and tempList is inserted into hashMap. But when the key is changed, i reset the templist and put new value to tempList. Then i put hashMap with new key and values, hashMap is also altered unwillingly. So i lost data in hashMap which is already stored. How can i prevent this?

Comment: Just don't reset the tempList but instead create a new one. You already seem to have figured out that resetting the tempList is your Problem (If i understand you correct). So just don't do it.

Comment: Not quite understanding your question. Post some code instead of describing the problem.

Comment: can you put your code please

Comment: Side note: Guava's [`Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) would greatly simplify this as you could just iterate over the list and call `put(key, object)` for each element. The map would handle creating all the sublists for you.

Comment: Create new list for every edit you do and then store it back to hash map which will avoid accidental data loss.